# Defining range of Time for ACK/NACK in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

in case of multiple consumer ,Is it possible to set the time within which consumer should acknowledge the rabbitmq server otherwise the message should be considered as not acknowledged by the RabbitMQ server and should be given to the other consumer?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this within RabbitMQ. In order to get something similar you can use a timer in your consumer and when the timer ends trigger a (n)ack of the message it is processing.